# getting empty response header ajax error for the Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iis, https

I am trying to get some HTML template files using javascript ajax call.

But every time it gives me "Failed to load resource: canceled" in safari browser. if I added HTTP instead of HTTPS then its working fine but for HTTPS it failed to load the resource every time.

I have tried to get the error response and it gives me the following error when I print the error.

Status text: "error"
Ready state: 4
Status: 404

here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
  url: "tpl/btntext.html",
  type: 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  datatype: 'text/html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
    console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders())
    console.log(textStatus)
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus)
    console.log(errorThrown)
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  }
});
```

This error occurs only Mac's Safari browser if I open the URL with HTTPS otherwise its working fine on other browsers.

I am using Microsoft-IIS/10.0 server.

Any idea?

Comment: Must be a server configuration issue, it works fine if I use another URL for the call on Safari: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzRWwW?editors=0010

Comment: @Armel But if i reload the page again then its working fine in safari as well.